# NSInternalInconsistencyException when presenting UIImagePickerController in camera mode but works fine in Photo Library mode

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` with `sourceType UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` on an iPhone 4 running iOS 7. It can be presented with the default `sourceType` (Photo Library) without issue, but when I try to present it in camera mode, it crashes with an `NSInternalInconsistencyException:`

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "vXZ-lx-hvc-view-kh9-bI-dsS" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

I am using a `UITableView` within the `UIViewController` that is presenting the `UIImagePickerController`, but I'm not clear on why the `UITableViewController` is coming up in the error. I have assigned the required delegates to the `UIViewController` `(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate)`.

Here is my code for presenting the `UIImagePickerController` from a `UIActionSheet`:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{
    //[self.tableView resignFirstResponder];
    _myPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    /*
    [_myPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [_myPicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [_myPicker setEditing:YES];
    [_myPicker setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [_myPicker setDelegate:self];
     */



    _myPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _myPicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    _myPicker.editing = YES;
    _myPicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _myPicker.delegate = self;

    //self.myPicker = _myPicker;
    [self presentViewController:_myPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

else if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    _myPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:_myPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


}
```

`_myPicker` is declared in the interface as:

```
@property(nonatomic)UIImagePickerController *myPicker;
```

and synthesized in the implementation:

```
@synthesize myPicker = _myPicker;
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message indicates that while you were loading a `UITableViewController` from a storyboard, the `view` property of view controller wasn't set to a UITableView.  Since nothing here loads a`UITableViewController` it seems unlikely the problem is in any of this code.  What have you done to isolate the problem to this code?

Comment: I tried removing the UITableView and all the associated IB connections from this view controller. Since this class that is doing the presenting is a UIViewController I am wondering why it's looking for a UITableView as the view property. Shouldn't it just be a UIView?

Comment: Looks like somewhere you forgot to set something back to `UIViewController` when you made those changes, because somewhere it's definitely loading a `UITableViewController`

Comment: Any idea why it would load the UIImagePickerController with the default sourceType (photo library) without any issues then?

Comment: No clue, as noted in my first comment, it seems really unlikely to have anything to do with code you've actually posted.

Comment: Try to present without animation.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: I'm using a xib for the UIViewController that is doing the presenting. I tried it with no animation and the problem persists..